# Incorporate Less in the lightning project

Tags: lightning, css, libraries

Is it possible to incorporate [Less](http://lesscss.org/) in the lightning project?

If possible, provide me with any manual on the topic you know about, please.

Here is what I tried out:

1. Uploaded [the](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.0.2/less.min.js) library file as a static resource to the salesforce.
2. Included it in one of my components.
3. Try to use the less benefits (in my case variables) in the `.css` of the component.

And the last steps fails:

[image]

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548692/can-less-be-used-with-visualforce-pages-reliably) question does not explain why my Less incorporation does not work out for me.

Comment: LDS internally uses SAAS. Is there a reason you want to use LESS instead of LDS?

Comment: @RedDevil, never heard about LDS. I just got used to LESS and after moving to salesforce would like to use it. Could you, please, provide me some kind of tutorials or manual on LDS? Since, I was not able to find [one](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=lds+saas&oq=lds+saas&aqs=chrome..69i57.2513j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: SLDS: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightning framework has [tokens](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_intro.htm) for this.

In case the link invalidates, please, just google `token design system salesforce`.